# How to get latest prices for each product, from prices table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel to build an online shop.
I have a table named 'products' and another table named 'prices'.
each product can have numerous amounts for price (which means there could be numerous records for one product_id in prices table).
I need to get the one latest price for each product_id and then filter them to be between two specific amounts. Could someone please tell me how could I do It's query?

Here is what I have done so far:

```
Product::whereHas('prices', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->groupBy('product_id')->whereBetween('amount', [0, 50000]);
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel supports adding a Relationship to access "One of Many", i.e. in your case, the "latest" Price from multiple associated prices. You should also be able to apply the price filtering directly within the method, or you can query on the fly via `->whereHas()` (or `->withWhereHas()`):

You'd define something like this:

```php
public function latestPrice(): HasOne {
  return $this->hasOne(Price::class)
  ->whereBetween('amount', [0, 50000])
  ->latestOfMany();
}
```

Then you'd use it as:

```php
$products = Product::with('latestPrice')->get();
```

Or, to make the method more generic:

```php
public function latestPrice(): HasOne {
  return $this->hasOne(Price::class)->latestOfMany();
}
```

And if you wanted to query for a specific range:

```php
$products = Product::with(['latestPrice' => function (Builder $query) {
  return $query->whereBetween('amount', [0, 50000]);
})->get();
```

*Sidenote, `->with()` is for Eager Loading, `->whereHas()` is used to filter  for products that have a `latestPrice`, `->withWhereHas()` is a combination; use the appropriate one for you use case.*

Full documentation can be found here:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-of-many

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is suppose to select amounts between a range from the latest prices of each product, not latest from the range.

Comment: *"filter them to be between two specific amounts"* - That's a very different issue than *"amounts between a range from the latest prices of each product"*...